# Export Excel to SQL without duplicate values

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have success making a connection between Excel and SQL with managing to add records from Excel cells to SQL database table and this is the tutorial i did:

[Export data from Excel to SQL Server](http://tomaslind.net/2013/12/26/export-data-excel-to-sql-server/)

a (Sign up form) i made in excel  [Sign up form i made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5oSF.png) , and i manage to make a Macro to (Sign Up) button to transfer the data into the SQL database and this is the code for a reference :

```
 Sub connect()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim iRowNo As Integer
   ' Dim sCustomerId, sFirstName, sLastName As String

    With Sheets("Sheet2")

        'Open a connection to SQL Server
        conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=seshbones\bones;Initial Catalog=fadi;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

        'Skip the header row
        iRowNo = 2

        'Loop until empty cell in CustomerId
        Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
            Name = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
            Location = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
            Age = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)
            ID = .Cells(iRowNo, 4)
            Mobile = .Cells(iRowNo, 5)
            Email = .Cells(iRowNo, 6)

            'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table
            conn.Execute "insert into dbo.test (Name, Location, Age, ID, Mobile, Email) values ('" & Name & "', '" & Location & "', '" & Age & "', '" & ID & "', '" & Mobile & "', '" & Email & "')"

            iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
        Loop

        MsgBox "Customers imported."

        conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing

    End With
 me in the table

End Sub
```

I want to make a restriction code to not duplicate the same Username in the table, for example if the customer enters a (Username) in excel cell and pressed (SignUP) there must have a function that check the SQL database and check the Username is already taken and refuse to make the exporting and message box appears "User is already taken" i hope you got my point.

Comment: Unique constraint is the best to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Could you not just get a count in your table for the specified `Username`. If the count is greater than 0, refuse to create the account with a: **Unable to create account because Username already exists** msg?

Comment: @IvanStarostin 
I did another table with (Primarykey) for the Name column as a test, the problem that i got an error through VBA in excel that tells : {  Violation of PRIMARY KEY } i want to notify the customer with friendly msg box not debug error.

Comment: @Zac i am a beginner can you give me an example of the COUNT code please

Comment: [Try This](https://www.lifewire.com/counting-values-with-sql-count-function-1019771). This should help you to write a `COUNT` query with `WHERE` clause

Comment: So catch the error and if it is a key violation then tell the user _hello! username is no go!_

Comment: Btw, PK should not be based on string data. Looks like you have an ID column - that's the candidate for PK. Unique constraint does not have to be PK at the same time.

Comment: @Fadi That's good, you can write an [answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help guys i added the error handler code to my project, so if there a duplicate records in my database it will prevent my program from shutting down and simply warn the user "Username Already taken" this is my how i fix the code :

```
 Sub Connect()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim iRowNo As Integer
   ' Dim sCustomerId, sFirstName, sLastName As String
 'Error handler
On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
```

`'Open a connection to SQL Server
    conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=seshbones\bones;Initial Catalog=fadi;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    'Skip the header row
    iRowNo = 2

    'Loop until empty cell in CustomerId
    Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
        Name = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
        Location = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
        Age = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)
        ID = .Cells(iRowNo, 4)
        Mobile = .Cells(iRowNo, 5)
        Email = .Cells(iRowNo, 6)

        'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table
        conn.Execute "insert into dbo.test (Name, Location, Age, ID, Mobile, Email) values ('" & Name & "', '" & Location & "', '" & Age & "', '" & ID & "', '" & Mobile & "', '" & Email & "')"

        iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
    Loop

    MsgBox "Customers imported."

    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing

End With

Exit Sub
ErrHandler:MsgBox "Username Already taken"  End Sub`